# Email with invalid hour in date header throws exception

Tags: python, email, datetime, python-3.6

Using Python 3.5 or 3.6, after loading an email with an invalid hour in the date header with the `email` package, attempting to access the `date` header throws a `ValueError` exception:

```
>>> import email
>>> from email import policy
>>> m = email.message_from_binary_file(open('bad_date.txt', 'rb'), policy=policy.default)
>>> m['date']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/email/message.py", line 391, in __getitem__
    return self.get(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/email/message.py", line 471, in get
    return self.policy.header_fetch_parse(k, v)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/email/policy.py", line 162, in header_fetch_parse
    return self.header_factory(name, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/email/headerregistry.py", line 586, in __call__
    return self[name](name, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/email/headerregistry.py", line 197, in __new__
    cls.parse(value, kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/email/headerregistry.py", line 303, in parse
    value = utils.parsedate_to_datetime(value)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/email/utils.py", line 214, in parsedate_to_datetime
    tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=tz)))
ValueError: hour must be in 0..23
```

This is the header from the email:

```
Date: Tue, 06 Jun 2017 27:39:33 +0600
```

(I'm analysing spam emails, and someone's spam sending program doesn't seem to understand how timezone conversions work. I've also seen negative hours...)

The `email` package is designed to cope with issues encountered while parsing emails by registering them as defects, so in this case, throwing an exception seems to be the wrong outcome.

I could try to update the default `header_factory` that's part of the `default` policy to deal with this situation, but it seems more like a bug in Python that `parsedate_to_datetime` behaves this way. (Apparently this behaviour is [on purpose](https://bugs.python.org/msg170558).)

UPDATE: I've raised this as a [Python bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue30681)

Comment: What do you want to happen? That date is set to `None`? Or something else?

Comment: Yes, I'd expect parsedate_to_datetime to return `None`, which would then be stored as the `datetime` attribute on the UniqueDateHeader object.

Comment: Also, the `DateHeader` class would need to modified slightly to register a defect, and not then try to further process the value returned from parsedate_to_datetime (since it would be `None`).

Answer (score 0):

Here's the workaround I've gone with for now:

```
from email import policy
from email import errors
from email import _header_value_parser as parser
from email.headerregistry import HeaderRegistry, DateHeader


class DateHeaderRobust(DateHeader):
    """
    Copied and updated from email/headerregistry.py to handle
    ValueError returned by parsedate_to_datetime when a date header
    has an invalid hour value (outside 0..23)
    """

    @classmethod
    def parse(cls, value, kwds):
        try:
            super().parse(value, kwds)
        except ValueError:
            kwds['defects'].append(
                errors.InvalidHeaderDefect('Invalid value in date'))
            kwds['datetime'] = None
            kwds['decoded'] = value
            kwds['parse_tree'] = parser.TokenList()


class UniqueDateHeader(DateHeaderRobust):
    max_count = 1


header_factory = HeaderRegistry()
header_factory.map_to_type('date', UniqueDateHeader)

email_policy = policy.default.clone(header_factory=header_factory)
```

And then when reading a message (e.g. with `email.message_from_binary_file)`, using `policy=email_policy` as a kwarg.